# Refer to subresource in two actions of custom resource

Tags: chef-infra

Suppose I have a custom resource that has it's main action as something like:

```rb
action :create do
  # some other stuff
  service "my-service" do
    action :start
  end
end
```

But I want resources external to the custom resource to be able to notify it to restart the service inside it.

`notifies :restart, 'service[my-service]', :delayed` doesn't work, because it can't find `service[my-service]`.

Is having a seperate action like:

```rb
action :restart
  service 'my-service' do
    action :restart
  end
end
```

the correct way to do this?

Is there a better way to refer to the same resource besides re-defining it in the restart action?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to this approach:

```
actionable = :create if something
actionable = :restart if something_else
```

and then modify your resources like this:

```
  service "my-service" do
    action actionable
  end
```

Comment: how would that allow me to do something like `notifies :restart, 'my_resource[my-name]', :delayed`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only notify up so if you need it to be visible to recipe code and other subresources you have to create it in the root run context:

```
action :create do
  with_run_context :root do
    edit_resource(:service, 'my-service') do |new_resource|
      action :nothing
      delayed_action :restart
    end
  end
end
```

That should create a service resource in the root run context and send a delayed restart to it.  The new_resource argument isn't necessary but it is a good habit to get into when using edit_resource.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to reverse the notification system and use `subscribes` to restart `my-service`. That way, we wouldn't need to handle it in the custom resource.

For example:

```rb
# shown for completeness of example
file '/tmp/testfile' do
  content 'foo'
end

service 'my-service.service' do
  action :nothing
  subscribes :restart, 'file[/tmp/testfile]', :delayed
end
```